# mysql- when i used subquery then it take so much time to execute why?

Tags: php, mysql

so i want to know why that take so much time.

my query is

```
SELECT prd.product_id,prd.product_name,
      (prd.product_price+po.additional_price) AS product_price,
       prd.date_added,po.discount,cat.category_name,payment_status,
      (SELECT COUNT(pi.product_impression_id) 
         FROM product_impression pi 
        WHERE pi.product_id = prd.product_id) AS impression_count 
  FROM products prd 
  INNER JOIN product_options po 
  ON po.product_id = prd.product_id 
  AND po.default_option = 'YES' 
  INNER JOIN categories cat 
  ON prd.product_category = cat.category_id 
  WHERE prd.product_artist_id = 103 
  ORDER BY prd.product_id DESC
```

when i remove following code form query then no issue.

```
(SELECT COUNT(pi.product_impression_id) 
 FROM product_impression pi 
 WHERE pi.product_id = prd.product_id) AS impression_count
```

please tell me why?

Comment: try like this `(SELECT COUNT(pi.product_impression_id)  AS impression_count
 FROM product_impression pi 
 WHERE pi.product_id = prd.product_id)`

Comment: no its not working same issue

Comment: `Indexing columns` will definitely improve the performance. Will be able to help If you can post the table structure.

Comment: sorry i can't post the table structure. i think that issue is subquery  with count or join

Answer (score 2):

We can use explain plan in oracle to find the execution plan of a query i.e., the kind of scanning the table does.  For eg: full table scan, index unique scan etc.

Try finding the execution plan of the above query using **explain**.

And check whether the indexes are used or not and also post the output of the explain so that we could analyze further.

thanks

Comment: i  want to know if i put join and Aggregate function in sub query then it take more time or not

Comment: I think we cant generalize it like that.  We need to analyze the execution plan of the query